# LibGDX Admob LinearLayout code

Tags: java, libgdx, admob, google-play-services, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to put the admob in my LIBGDX application, but by following the tutorial GitHub and I can not run my application. Please someone tries to help me set up the code. Below is main_activity, main.xml.
Note: All modifications were made in AndroidManifest.xml as tutorial google admob.

Main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/main_layout"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
```

MainAcitivity:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication implements AdsController {

private static final String BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-3954521267929789/5402418153";

AdView bannerAd;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    cfg.useGL20 = false;

    View gameView = initializeForView(new FXGame(this), cfg);
    setupAds();

    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    layout.addView(gameView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    layout.addView(bannerAd, params);

    setContentView(layout);
}

public void setupAds() {
    bannerAd = new AdView(this);
    bannerAd.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    bannerAd.setBackgroundColor(0xff000000); // black
    bannerAd.setAdUnitId(BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID);
    bannerAd.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
}

@Override
public void showBannerAd() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            bannerAd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
            AdRequest ad = builder.build();
            bannerAd.loadAd(ad);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void hideBannerAd() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            bannerAd.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
}
```

MY FXGame:

```
 public class FXGame extends Game {

private AdsController adsController;

public ZBGame(AdsController adsController){
    this.adsController = adsController;
}

@Override
public void create() {
    AssetLoader.load();
    setScreen(new SplashScreen(this));
    adsController.showBannerAd();

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    AssetLoader.dispose();
}
}
```

Interface AdsController:

```
public interface AdsController {

public void showBannerAd();
public void hideBannerAd();

}
```

Comment: You are not doing anything for displaying a banner or interstitial ad. You can follow step explained in this article series : http://www.norakomi.com/tutorial_admob_part2_banner_ads1.php

After trying something if you still can not integrate admob with your libgdx project, I can help you.

Comment: I had already done for this tutorial, but does not show the banner. With this tutorial did not have any bugs in my code, just in AdsController in project-core. If you can help me, it will look great! haha

Comment: Can you please show your code for showing the banner ad?

Comment: Where is your AdView? Where did you set it's properties.

Comment: Updated my question. Following the tutorial Noragami, it appears only a black stripe in the bottom. It does not show the ad.

Comment: "I can not run my application" What does this mean? What happens?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting visibility of bannerAd wrong in your showBannerAd and hideBannerAd methods. It should be opposite. Additionaly please ensure that you are calling show showBannerAd().

Comment: How can I fix this? If you can help me

Comment: @MTR Look closely at your calls to `setVisibility()`. If you want to **show** the banner do you really want it to be invisible?

Comment: @MTR, I have edited your code. In setupAds method default visibility is set to INVISIBLE. After calling showBannerAd method, your ads will be shown.

Comment: Even changing the visibility in both still appears only a black stripe in the bottom. I want to show the Smart banner

Comment: Can you please show me the code you calling "showBannerAd" method

Comment: http://www.norakomi.com/tutorial_admob_part2_banner_ads2.php is the interface of this tutorial

Comment: I need to see your ZBGame.java implementation. Where do you call showBannerAd in this class? If you don't call it anywhere it will not be visible. If you want to make it visible as default, you should load add in your setupAds method.

Comment: private AdsController adsController;
 
public MyGdxGame(AdsController adsController){
    this.adsController = adsController;
}

Comment: I don't know whether I can explain more clearly but you are here only setting your local field adsController. Do you call adsController.showBannerAd() in anywhere?

Comment: Please see the site, I made all the changes there

Comment: Ok, please replace your setupAds method with this one : 


public void setupAds() {
    bannerAd = new AdView(this);
    bannerAd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    bannerAd.setBackgroundColor(0xff000000);
    bannerAd.setAdUnitId(BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID);
    bannerAd.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);

    AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
    AdRequest ad = builder.build();
    bannerAd.loadAd(ad);
}

Comment: You forget to call adsController.showBannerAd(); in your "create" method of FXGame. Please double check http://www.norakomi.com/tutorial_admob_part2_banner_ads2.php

Comment: I added Controller.showBannerAd ads () but after this change, my application doesn't run. It displays an error in the AVD as well as use the smartphone (debbug USB). I can't find the error.

Comment: Can you please update your code, so we can see what is the problem. If your application crashes you can see the stacktrace on "adb logcat".

Comment: Updated! I can't start the application. If I don't implement the AdsController interface , the application runs but only shows a black box instead of the Smart Banner!

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't start the application" ? What is happening? What is the error? Where is your stacktrace?

Comment: "Unfortunately the application has stopped", if I remove the Add Controller interface, the application can start. I use AVD Genymotion

Comment: Ok, think you missed my last two question @MTR. What is the error? Where is your stacktrace? You can check it by using logcat messages. You can simply use logcat by writing "adb logcat" on any console or command prompt. We can not help you without see the stacktrace.